# Pytorch autograd for linear elasticity

Tags: pytorch, physics, autograd

I'm trying to solve the linear elastic problem, with the equilibrium governing equations given as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mYz1.png)

Suppose I have the displacement matrix containing n point-wise displacement $u\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 2}$, which comes from the coordinates $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 2}$

However, the Pytorch neural networks leads to very bad results, I was still suspecting I made some mistakes on calculating the gradient by torch.autograd function after checking my codes several times. Could anyone please give me some suggestions?

For $\epsilon_{ij}=0.5(u_{i,j}+u_{j,i})$, I have two functions:

```
def calculate_Jacobians(u,X):
    J = []
    _,d=u.shape
    for i in range(d):
        u_i = u[:, i]
        grad = torch.autograd.grad(u_i, X,grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(u_i).to(u.device), create_graph=True)[0]
        #print('grad:',grad)
        J.append(grad)
    return torch.stack(J, dim=1)

def u_to_e(u,X):
    Jacobian=calculate_Jacobians(u,X)
    strain=0.5*(Jacobian+torch.transpose(Jacobian,-1,-2))
    return strain
```

The Jacobian is presented in a batch manner which has shape (n,2,2).

For $\sigma_{ij}=\lambda\delta_{ij}\sum_{k=1}^2\epsilon_{kk}+2\mu\epsilon_{ij}$, I have three functions:

```
def batch_eye(x):
    n,d=x.shape[:-1]
    return torch.eye(d, d, dtype=x.dtype, device=x.device).unsqueeze(0).repeat(n, 1, 1)
def batch_trace(x):
    return x.diagonal(offset=0, dim1=-1, dim2=-2).sum(-1,keepdim=True).unsqueeze(-1)

def e_to_sigma(strain,lamb,mu):
    return lamb*batch_eye(strain)*batch_trace(strain)+2*mu*strain
```

After obtaining the stress, I have to calculate the divergence of stress wrt to all directions, i.e.,
$\sum_{i=1}^2\sigma_{ij,i}=0,;\forall j=1,2$
I have one function for this:

```
def point_wise_divergence(stress,X):
    _,d=X.shape
    div=[]
    for i in range(d):
        sigma_col=stress[:,:,i]
        grad=torch.autograd.grad(sigma_col, X,grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(sigma_col), create_graph=True)[0]
        div.append(grad)
    Div_comp=torch.stack(div,dim=1)
    Div=Div_comp.sum(-1)
    return Div
```

For the displacement gradient, it's easy to have an example problem from text books, but I'm not sure I did it correctly for stress divergence.